# Ignore .env file on unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, phpdotenv

Most of my classes include loading env variables for configuration. When I was coding I thought [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) ignored the `.env` file on testing environments since there is already a conf file like `phpunit.xml` where you define them.

Is it possible to make dotenv ignore .env when on testing environment?

Comment: You can't ignore the .env file but if the environment variable is set before the .env file is loaded, the predefined variable is used, unless the .env file is called using the `$dotenv->overload` method. I don't think Laravel does the latter. This means that the environment variables defined in phpunit.xml will not be overriden.

Comment: I was trying to use the default value `env('myVar', $defaultValue)` so that I didn't have to set it on `phpunit.xml`, but it seems like it can't be done :(

Comment: You could declare the environment variables within your testcase before the application is booted. But that won't let you use the default values still. I usually reserve the default values for my production server so I never need a .env file on my live.

Answer (score 1):

Testing will use your `.env` file, but you can override any of its settings in `phpunit.xml`.

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="DB_DRIVER" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="CACHE_HOST" value="localhost"/>
    <env name="SESSION_HOST" value="localhost"/>
</php>
```